# How to take mobility into account: multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, modeling, panel-data

I have a panel including two years and I want to compare urban and rural wages:

$\log \text{wage}_{it} =\beta_0 +\beta_1\text{urban}_{it} +\beta_2\text{educ}_{it}+\beta_3\text{exper}_{it}+ \beta_4\text{exper}_{it}^2+\delta_2+\nu_it$

urban is a dummy as well as $\delta_2$ for the second year

How to I take into account that people might have changed location over time? Wealthy people might have moved to the city and thus raised the difference in urban and rural wages. Should I add a dummy variable or even an interaction variable..?
I'm working with R and I use fixed effects and first difference regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a location variable that has four levels: Urban-urban, urban-rural, rural-urban and rural-rural. Then this would only get an i subscript.